# MySQL Recurring event not executing

Tags: mysql, session, events

I have a recurring event set to execute each 1 minute in MySQL:

```
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM session WHERE `date` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);
END
```

For some reason, my session entries, such as one with the date parameter of

> 2019-01-19 18:28:24

are not being deleted, despite the fact that `SELECT NOW();` currently returns

> 2019-01-19 18:44:15

So this is more than a minute after the creation date and proves that timezones aren't the problem. Is my event simply failing to execute or is there a problem with the event itself?

**EDIT: Please note that the event is set to execute each minute AND delete session entries that are more than a minute old, not just one or the other. The recurring interval isn't shown above, but I've confirmed that it is 1 minute.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to run

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = on;
```

in order to fix the issue. I had rebooted my XAMPP local server since the last time I tested this, which is why it suddenly stopped working.